# What is the difference between MediaTomb basic Mediatomb-daemon and MediaTomb-common

Tags: mediatomb

If I want to install MediaTomb on my Ubuntu 16.04 system to stream on my LG Smart TV I got the choice of MediaTomb basic
Mediatomb-daemon
and MediaTomb-common
Can somebody help me to explain wht the difference is?
Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0):

You should read the description of each, for example,

`apt-cache show mediatomb-daemon` tells us the following:

> This package contains the files needed to run mediatomb as a daemon.

...and  `apt-cache show mediatomb-common`:

> This package contains the binary, the manpage, and everything needed
>   for  scripting and the web interface.

If you simulate an install of mediatomb, this is what happens:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -s mediatomb
...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  javascript-common libjs-prototype libmysqlclient18 mediatomb-common
  mediatomb-daemon mysql-common
```

As you can see, mediatomb-common, mediatomb-daemon and some other packages can be viewed as different parts (aka dependencies) of the mediatomb package.